# Timestamp off by a factor of 1000

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

From the Snowflake web interface:

```
create table example (a TIMESTAMP_NTZ);
insert into example (a) values (current_timestamp);
select * from example;
```

yields:

```
2020-09-16 10:28:45.271
```

Now, from my terminal:

```
Python 3.7.9 (tags/v3.7.9:13c94747c7, Aug 17 2020, 18:58:18) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> import snowflake.connector
>>> import snowflake.connector.pandas_tools
>>> import datetime

>>> connection = snowflake.connector.connect(user="x", account="x.us-east-1.privatelink", authenticator="externalbrowser")
Initiating login request with your identity provider. A browser window should have opened for you to complete the login. If you can't see it, check existing browser windows, or your OS settings. Press CTRL+C to abort and try again...

>>> connection.cursor().execute("USE ROLE x")      
<snowflake.connector.cursor.SnowflakeCursor object at 0x0000022D82B73508>
>>> connection.cursor().execute("USE WAREHOUSE x")   
<snowflake.connector.cursor.SnowflakeCursor object at 0x0000022D82DB8A48>
>>> connection.cursor().execute("USE DATABASE x")
<snowflake.connector.cursor.SnowflakeCursor object at 0x0000022D82D7DB08>
>>> connection.cursor().execute("ALTER SESSION SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIERS_IGNORE_CASE = TRUE")
<snowflake.connector.cursor.SnowflakeCursor object at 0x0000022D82D73C48>
>>> connection.cursor().execute("USE SCHEMA x")
<snowflake.connector.cursor.SnowflakeCursor object at 0x0000022D82D6EB08>

>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'A': pd.Timestamp('2020-09-16 12:34:56')}, index=[0]) 
>>> success, num_chunks, num_rows, output = snowflake.connector.pandas_tools.write_pandas(conn=connection, df=df, table_name="example")
>>> output
[('nrjuc/file0.txt', 'LOADED', 1, 1, 1, 0, None, None, None, None)]
```

Now, again from the Snowflake web interface:

```
select * from example;
```

yields:

```
2020-09-16 10:28:45.271
52680-03-18 01:13:20.000
```

I would like to know why that second date (52680-03-18 01:13:20.000) as inserted by the write_pandas is incorrect (by a factor of almost 1000).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Better workaround as supplied by Snowflake Corp.:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [pd.Timestamp('2020-09-16 12:34:56', tz='UTC')]})
```

With this approach your dataframe column remains a datetime, rather than becoming a float.

Answer (score 1):

A workaround ... change:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': pd.Timestamp('2020-09-16 12:34:56')}, index=[0])
```

to

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': pd.Timestamp('2020-09-16 12:34:56').timestamp()}, index=[0])
```

The .timestamp() method converts the datetime to a float, and Snowflake seems to interpret the resulting float as the number of seconds past the epoch and converts to a Snowflake timestamp.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, date columns looked fine in python but appeared as miliseconds in Snowflake, i ve solved it by converting np.datetime64 to object:

```
output['SUBMODEL_VALUE_DATE'] =output['SUBMODEL_VALUE_DATE'].dt.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
```