# Snowflake displaying wrong Date

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, timestamp, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'm trying to write date column from my python dataframe to snowflake.
However, snowflake is displaying wrong values/year in the table.

Example:

I try to insert: `2010-10-15T00:00:00.000Z`

What snowflake displays: `40788570-09-06 17:00:00.000`

When the same is passed in String datatype, it displays the datetime correctly.
Can someone please guide, Thank you.

Comment: Show us the code, please.

Comment: Have added the code Tim, for other dataframes also the function is used, so I believe here we are using only the last few lines of the function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Snowflake has a number of ways to parse epoch timestamps, I am not familiar with the panda/python side how to make it happy, but can show you what is happening.

```
SELECT '2010-10-15T00:00:00.000Z'::timestamp as t1,
    '40788570-09-06 17:00:00.000'::timestamp as t2,
    date_part(epoch_second, t1) as e1,
    date_part(epoch_second, t2) as e2,
    to_timestamp(e1) as tt1,
    to_timestamp(e2, 6) as tt2;
```

| T1 | T2 | E1 | E2 | TT1 | TT2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2010-10-15 00:00:00.000 | Invalid date | 1,287,100,800 | 1,287,100,799,974,800 2010-10-15 00:00:00.000 | 2010-10-14 23:59:59.974 |  |

basically you python date is epoch_microsecond, and the default transform is treating it as epoch seconds, so when it's parsed with the correct level it's more or less correct (it's wrong here due to coverting the wildly future date to `s` and then read that is `us`)..

Comment: Hey Simeon it does help really, need to find a way to do it in Python/pandas though! Thank you so much!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63922508/timestamp-off-by-a-factor-of-1000

Comment: I had inspected the link before, but after you shared I tried to implement it again and it worked. Thank you Simeon.

Comment: But it show some time difference, which I had to look up which got handled by changing the timezone, it got resolved finally though :)